# Why first linq act 20 times faster than second one [Getting Max value]

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Can someone explain why there is a huge difference about 20 times between these methods !?
The difference between 2 times and 4 times is acceptable to my logic but I can't understand why this happen on 20 times.

Code :

```
//Method 1 which took 00:00:00.82
DateTime at = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    var x = (from m in brd.MohreHa select new { m, am = m.GetPossibleMoves().Count() }).OrderByDescending(o => o.am).First().m;

}
var att = DateTime.Now - at;


//Method 2 which took 00:00:15.31
DateTime bt = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var y = brd.MohreHa.First(m => m.GetPossibleMoves().Count() == brd.MohreHa.Max(a => a.GetPossibleMoves().Count()));
}
        var btt = DateTime.Now - bt;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second has to compute the `Max()` for *every single item in your collection*.  This effectively makes the `brd.MohreHa.First` call quadratic, since it's going to be checking against every item once for each item.

The first option only does the `Count()` call each time, and then does a single ordering at the end.  This avoids the need to enumerate for `Max()` N times.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any better way to run this query 1000 times which is faster than my methods ?

Comment: @Mahdi It'd be far faster if you didn't use LINQ, and just kept track of the "max" item... That'd avoid the sort entirely.